# CloudFlare Invalid SSL certificate

Tags: laravel, nginx, cloudflare, laravel-8

I have a Laravel 8 application.

I have no idea what I missed. I'm trying to deploy a site in my server.

I kept getting :

**Invalid SSL certificate**

https://mybabies.app/

---

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mybabies.app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mybabies.app.key; 

    server_name mybabies.app www.mybabies.app;

    root /home/bheng/mybabies/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    client_max_body_size 500M;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|mp3|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|woff2|woff)$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }


    location / {
        #limit_req zone=one burst=2 nodelay;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }

}
```

I already create `crt` + `pem` key in CloudFlare and configure in these 2 lines :

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mybabies.app.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mybabies.app.key;
```

---

## Edit

When I paused it

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I clicked `View Certificate`, I see

[image]

---

## Updated

I created the cert from

[image]

Comment: Probably you are using `Full (strict)` encryption on CloudFlare, you can get rid of the problem by changing `Flexible` mode on your CloudFlare's **SSL/TLS** section

Comment: @EsTeAa it will disable SSL between cloudflare and server. It fixes symptoms, not not source of problem. If ignoring SSL then by using full (not full scrict), not flexible. Also author is trying to set up correct certificates on server, so issue should be fixed there.

Comment: @cyber8200 disable CF for now, and check if/what certificate is returned by server

Comment: @chojnicki : I paused CF for now. I got `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID` - you may see it. https://mybabies.app/

Comment: @chojnicki : what else should I do ?

Comment: @cyber8200 where did you generated certificates in CF panel exactly?

Comment: @chojnicki : SSL > Client Cert.

Comment: I also updated my post with screenshot. Let me know if you guys need other info.

Comment: @cyber8200 now everything is clear ;)

Comment: To resolve the issue we need to enable the proxy for all A, AAAA, and CNAME records using cloudflare dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To setup secure connection between Cloudflare and your server you need to generate **Origin CA Certificate** in page *Origin Certificates*, but you did this in *Client Certificates* instead, so that's why you are getting error.

They are completelly different things with different purpose. Read descriptions.

#### Client Certificates

> Secure and authenticate your APIs and web
> applications with client certificates. Block traffic from devices that
> do not have a valid client SSL/TLS certificate with mTLS rules.

#### Origin Certificates

> Generate a free TLS certificate signed by Cloudflare to install on
> your origin server. Origin Certificates are only valid for encryption
> between Cloudflare and your origin server.

After generating PEM an KEY you need to put them in .crt and .key and load in nginx config, like you did before.

```
listen 443;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mybabies.app.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mybabies.app.key;
```

Now connection **Full (strict)** should work.

If you want to use self-signed certificate instead, but still leverage secure connection between CF and server, then use option **Full** instead (without strict). By using **Flexible** your visitor will be still using HTTPS, but there will be no SSL connection between CF and server, and server will see this as HTTP connection, so this option is not recommended.

Rad more: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-

Comment: I think you're correct. I solved that now. :) I got 404 now. I think it's something. esle.